# Nginx does not display custom 404 page with Gunicorn + Flask

Tags: nginx, flask, gunicorn, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I'm trying to display a custom 404 error page on my site, but it seems that Nginx does not catch the 404. Instead, `it shows a 404 page from Gunicorn(flask app)`

nginx.conf:

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
server_name example.com www.example.com;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://flask:8080/;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect off;
}

error_page 404 /notfound.html;
location /notfound.html {
    root /var/www/html;
}

error_page 500 502 503 504 /maintenance.html;
location /maintenance.html {
    root /var/www/html;
}
}
```

Both flask app and Nginx are running on separate docker containers.

> I purposefully brought the flask app down to see what happens, after a
> while It redirects to 504(Timeout) and the maintenance.html appeared. - works fine.

But on a 404 error instead of displaying this custom `notfound.html`, it displays a `404 Not Found` from Flask App (The 404 page did not had any nginx version on it).

Comment: Use [`proxy_intercept_errors`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_intercept_errors) directive: `proxy_intercept_errors on;`

Comment: Oh! I didn't thought it would be that easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`proxy_intercept_errors on;` should solve this problem.